# black UIImagePicker preview ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting a black image picker preview. This DOES NOT happen if I delete the app then run it again. So the first time the app runs after being installed to my device it works. However if I bring up my image picker controller after that and capture an image, the preview is black. I have read all the answers mentioning background threading but I am not running any background threads. Im not sure what is causing this. It works perfectly the first time around but after that it never works.

```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Image Picker settings
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;


    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    } else {

        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

            //dismiss view controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't present the image picker from the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller. When `viewDidLoad` is being run, your view controller hasn't yet been added to the view controller hierarchy. You can try presenting it from `viewDidAppear`, and that might fix it.

Comment: You're not calling [super viewWillAppear:animated] according to your edit, and my answer said to do it in viewDidAppear:, not viewWillAppear:, because in viewWillAppear:, it still isn't to the point where you should try presenting anything from it.

Comment: It needs to be in viewWill, if I put it in viewDid my view is visible for a second before the image picker comes up.

Comment: should I try using 2 different view controllers for this? one to display the image picker and then segue to my other view when an image is picked?

Comment: Try it in viewDidAppear: and see if it fixes the problem. Because I don't think it will work right doing it from viewWillAppear:, so I'm pretty sure that's why you're having the issue. It can't properly present a modal view controller from one that's not yet itself done displaying.

Comment: moved it to viewDiDAppear.still the same issue.